# How to change the bundle identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to change the bundle identifier of my app currently it is displaying the com.example.ProductName398479kdfkls with some key i have tried it through changing from info tab under target but what is this Product Name under build settings??
Why we use product name ??

Comment: Change it from plist!

Comment: But i am asking why product name is appended in the bundle identifier & why we use product name & for what purpose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this :

1) Select your target

2) Select 'info' tab (you can do the same by finding the plist file on the project)

3) Search for "Bundle Identifier" key, The value on your end should be com.mycompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}.

f you want to change the grey field just replace the "com.mycompany" with whatever you want. the other field is the "Product Name" (which is read dynamically from the relevant key), You can change it by set the "Product Name" key on "Build Settings". You can also do it pretty ugly and change all the bundle identifier to whatever you want but I don't recommend that because if you would add more targets it would be static and harder to maintain.

I got  here :[How to change the bundle identifier of an app in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501393/how-to-change-the-bundle-identifier-of-an-app-in-xcode-5)