# How to change the Build name in Xcode? (Image to show what I mean is down below)

Tags: ios, xcode

So I downloaded a open source Xcode project and now I am modifying it a lot and want it to be in my name but in Xcode I see these two names how do I change these 2 names?

Here is an image to show clear view what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0CuF.jpg

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501393/how-to-change-the-bundle-identifier-of-an-app-in-xcode-5  this may help?

Answer (score 0):

On the `Xcode`, where is the your app hierarchy, make a long double click just like you rename a folder, and rename!

Hope this helps!